# How to store only the latest API response in Rails VCR Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, vcr

We are using the [Ruby VCR library](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to mock and replay responses from various APIs.

In one function that we have, our code continuously polls an API endpoint until the response is ready. The VCR Cassette is storing each of these polling requests, with the "Not Ready" response. At the very end of the cassette, the actual response is stored.

How can I configure VCR to store only the last and actual response? I can go into the YML file and manually delete the polling requests, but I would prefer an automated way since I would have to delete these requests on every new cassette recording.

The main reason why I want to delete these polling requests is due to the time it takes to run our tests (we have a lengthy sleep in our code between each unsuccessful poll).

Comment: How often do you update your VCRs? In theory it should not be that often, so you could keep one "Not Ready" response (testing polling behaviour) and one regular response. I had a similar issue with access tokens being put into VCR and I only had to update the cassettes a few times so far. I have a feeling that VCR does not offer this feature.

Comment: Every 90 days. Yeah, that's the current approach that I'm taking, using a shorter sleep if we're in a test environment. Thanks for the input.